# return string without punctuation

Tags: python

I'm a beginner who'd like to return strings in pairs of characters. If the input to the function is odd then the last pair it to include an `_`.

Example: `solution("asdfadb")` should return `['as', 'df', 'ad', 'b_']`

My code however, returns: `['a', 's']['d', 'f']['a', 'd']['b', '_']`

I've tried multiple ways and cannot get it to return the correctly formatted result:

```
def solution(s):
    if len(s)%2 != 0:
        s = "".join((s, "_"))
    s = list(s)
    s = [ s[i:i+2] for i in range(0 , len(s) , 2) ]
    s = ''.join(str(pair) for pair in s )
    print(s)

solution("asdfadb")
['a', 's']['d', 'f']['a', 'd']['b', '_']
```

Comment: making the string into a list first is unnecessary, you can use string into a for-loop directly and also have plenty of the same properties of a list, in fact you can think of a string like a sort of list of characters

Comment: and thus all you need to do is `s = [ s[i:i+2] for i in range(0 , len(s) , 2) ]` and your check to the `_` character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a small confusion in the last list comprehension, try this (see my comment):

```
def solution(s):
    if len(s)%2 != 0:
        s = "".join((s, "_"))
    s = list(s)
    s = [ s[i:i+2] for i in range(0 , len(s) , 2) ]
    s = [''.join(pair) for pair in s] # For each sublist (aka pair) - do join.
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
['as', 'df', 'ad', 'b_']
```

Comment: making the string into a list is a completely unnecessary step

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit more compact than @idanz answer, but the principle is the same:

```py
def solution(s: str):
    s = s + "_" if len(s) % 2 !=0 else s
    pairs = [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
    print(pairs)

solution("asdfadb")
```

Output:

```py
['as', 'df', 'ad', 'b_']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using a list comprehension, string slicing, and zip_longest:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


def solution(string):
    return ["".join(pair) for pair in zip_longest(string[0::2], string[1::2], fillvalue="_")]


print(solution("asdfadb"))
```

Output:

```
['as', 'df', 'ad', 'b_']
```